# wget time measurement

Tags: ubuntu, time, wget

I am using wget for http traffic measurement. Since the network is quick and the http data is small in size, wget cannot measure time and rate of the download session. So how could I measure the time? Maybe someone could help providing a script or another application that is capable of solving this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try `curl` in place of `wget`. I think it might output the relevant statistics.

Answer (score 40):

As alluded to by [user1718019](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1718019/user1718019), curl can do this for you:

```
curl -so /dev/null -w '%{time_total}\n' http://www.example.com/
```

This will print on `stdout`, according to the manual:

> The total time, in seconds, that the full operation lasted. The time will be displayed with millisecond resolution.

Comment: Keep in mind that curl and 'time wget' return different times for the same URL, so once you have decided between curl or 'time wget', don't change your measurement tool.

Answer (score 28):

Try something like `time wget http://whatever.com`.

Comment: From the `time` page: "Note: some shells (e.g., bash(1)) have a built-in time command that provides similar information on the usage of time and possibly other resources.To access the real command, you may need to specify its pathname (something like /usr/bin/time)."